# How to access item count in TestComplete for BCGPGridCtrl

Tags: testcomplete, syslistview32

I am using TestComplete to record SmokeTests.

I have upgraded UI from **SysListView32** to **BCGPGridCtrl**. Now, i am not able to access count of items in that grid using TestComplete. Is there any way to get count of items in the grid ?

Looking for solution from anyone come across this issue !!